# MySQL query for matching same coordinates

Tags: mysql, database, join, latitude-longitude

I am working on database to get same coordinates records. But I am unable to do it. Below is the query I have set.

```
SELECT * FROM `survey` s1, `survey` s2
    WHERE s1.`latitude` = s2.`latitude`
      AND s1.`longitude`= s2.`longitude`
```

But still it's not giving me the correct data. The upper written query is just for reference the actual query that I am working on is

```
SELECT  sur.id AS 'Survey ID',DATE (sur.capture_date) AS 'Date',
        sur.sub_division AS 'Sub-Div', sd.name AS 'Sub-Div Name',
        sd.`circle_name` AS 'Circle Namse',sur.ref_no AS 'Reference Number',
        sur.customer_id AS 'Customer ID', sur.consumer_name AS 'Consumer Name & Address',
        sur.sync_date AS 'Sync Date', sur.capture_date AS 'Capture Date',
        sur.latitude AS Latitude, sur.longitude AS Longitude,
        sur.near_by_place AS Comments, sur.tarrif AS Tariff, sur.s_load AS 'Sanctioned Load',
        sur.meter_type AS 'Meter Type (IT)', sur.meter_type_field AS 'Meter Type (Field)',
        sur.meter_type_desired AS 'Meter Type (As Desired By SDO)',
        sur.pole_type AS 'Pole Type', sur.meter_location AS 'Meter Location',
        sur.est_cable_len AS 'Estimated Cable Length', sur.meter_status AS 'Meter Status',
        sur.running_load_entry_a AS 'Running Load Entry (A)',
        sur.running_load_entry_b AS 'Running Load Entry (B)',
        sur.running_load_entry_c AS 'Running Load Entry (C)',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Zong%' THEN sn.signal_strength END) AS Zong,
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Zong%'THEN sn.operator_type END) AS 'Zong Operator Type',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Zong%' THEN sn.data_rate/1024 END) AS 'Zong Data Rate (Mbps)',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Ufone%'THEN sn.signal_strength END) AS Ufone,
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Ufone%'THEN sn.operator_type END) AS 'Ufone Operator Type',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Ufone%'THEN sn.data_rate/1024 END) AS 'Ufone Data Rate (Mbps)',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Telenor%'THEN sn.signal_strength END) AS Telenor,
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Telenor%'THEN sn.operator_type END) AS 'Telenor Operator Type',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Telenor%'THEN sn.data_rate/1024 END) AS 'Telenor Data Rate (Mbps)',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Mobilink%'THEN sn.signal_strength END) AS Mobilink,
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Mobilink%'THEN sn.operator_type END) AS 'Mobilink Operator Type',
        MAX(CASE WHEN sn.operator_name LIKE '%Mobilink%'THEN sn.data_rate/1024 END) AS 'Mobilink Data Rate (Mbps)'
    FROM survey sur
    INNER JOIN  survey_networks sn  ON sur.id = sn.survey_id
    INNER JOIN  survey_hesco_subdivision sd  ON sur.sub_division = sd.sub_div_code
    WHERE  sur.id > 4253
    GROUP BY  sur.id ,sur.sub_division ,sur.ref_no ,sur.customer_id ,
        sur.consumer_name , sur.consumer_address , sur.sync_date ,
        sur.capture_date , sur.source , sur.latitude , sur.longitude ,
        sur.near_by_place , sur.tarrif , sur.s_load , sur.meter_type ,
        sur.meter_type_field , sur.meter_type_desired , sur.pole_type ,
        sur.meter_location , sur.est_cable_len , sur.meter_status ,
        sur.running_load_entry_a , sur.running_load_entry_b ,
        sur.running_load_entry_c
    ORDER BY  sur.`id` ASC
```

It gives me all the records having same and different coordinates. I just want to get all the records having same coordinates.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, your actual query is illegible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below query to your where clause.I hope this will help you.

Let me explain you below query. Subquery is searching for latitude and longitude if they are more than once.

```
and ( select case when COUNT(*) > 1 then true else false end 
      from survey s2 
      where sur.latitude = s2.latitude and s2.longitude = sur.longitude
      and sur.id > 4253 
      GROUP BY s2.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, I can't see any condition saying that latitude=latitude and longitude=longitude. You probably need to add a condition like this in the "ON" clause of the join(s).

Comment: Both latitude and longitude are in the same table

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the first, there is no self join present in the second query. Please revisit once again.

Comment: I have added this `INNER JOIN survey s1 ON sur.latitude = s1.latitude AND sur.longitude = s1.longitude` but still it gives me all the records